# Display loader image with Opacity on Page Laod not working in IE 9 and earlier

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I want display loader image on page load 
I'm applying it with opacity 
and at same time background links not clickable. 
The below  code working fine in FF,Chrome,
But it having some issue with IE browser 
-When opacity loader image displayed at the same time background links are clickable. I don't want those link as clickable while loader image displaying.

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function() {     
});    

function displayLoader()     
{         
alert('hello');     
$('#load').html('<img src="../images/icn/loader.gif"/>');     

$("#load").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%");       

$("#load").addClass("load");    

$("#divPage").addClass("loaderStyle");    
}     

</script>         
<div id="divPage" style="background:#F2F2F2;height:500px;">   
<a onclick="displayLoader();" href="#">click me</a>   
<div id="load"></div>   
</div>    

and **CSS**    
.loaderStyle    
{     
opacity: 0.80;       
filter: alpha(opacity=80);     
}     

#load     
{    
position: absolute;    
/*margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;*/    
z-index: 1000;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding background color and please don't forget to refer others answers

```
#load 
{
   /* position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;*/
    position: absolute;
    background:#333;
    left:0;
    top:0;    
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$("#load").css({
    "width":"100%",
    "height":"100%",
    "opacity":"0.8"
});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: @Saeed - could you please help him out of this, and I requast to elaborate more. because I've same issue

Comment: for user867399: use left and top css properties because you have used absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for IE8 and earlier support, this should do the trick

```
$("#load").css({
    "width":"100%",
    "height":"100%",
    "opacity":"0.8",
    "filter":"alpha(opacity=80)"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You visit this link,you can find your issue in this link

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

and use this code for optimize your code

```
$("#load").css({"width":"100%","height":"100%"})

/* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
```